# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.React.Component')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app in react-native while running the app I get this error.

[image: Error Image]

My `index.js` file

```
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

My `App.js` file

````
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Routes from './src/store/Routes';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#18163E" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Routes />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

}); ```

While running i am getting above error and it is pointed to index.js file
````

Comment: Where you imported 'AppRegistry'? Can you show us more code of 'index.js'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message clearly states the React component missing.

In your App.js file add the below line:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

All of your react components should have this line.

After adding the above line your App.js file will appear as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Routes from './src/store/Routes';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#18163E" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Routes />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is missing.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to import `AppRegistry` from react-native?